# git server and client set up in linux

Tags: linux, git

i am new to git and now i am  trying to set up a git server and want to access the server from client.

referred many links but those are not helping me. i tried with the link http://davedevelopment.co.uk/2010/12/05/how-to-install-gitolite-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat.html. after the final step in the document i didn't know how to proceed.

can anyone give the details? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you have trouble adding users or cloning your repos at whatever is your server address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is missing on the above answers is how to push on the server a new repo.

Suppose that in the gitolite config file you have a repo named my_repo, you can add to the server an existing local repo this way:

```
cd my_repo
git remote add gitolite git@your.git.server:my_repo
git push gitolite master
```

You have to type ONLY ONCE the second line above. After that, you only have to push.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249088/how-to-set-up-private-git-server-on-linux referred the above link to set up a linux git server and client. now its working. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you have cloned a repository on your client you are ready to start coding...

```
git commit
```

to commit changes locally, and

```
git push
```

to push your changes to the server.